# Conditionally Adding Styles to Datatables Rows in Print View

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, datatables

I am trying to style specific rows in the Datatables print view.

I have a table that has rows o financial items. They are grouped by invoice number and after the invoice is completed, a summary row is shown:

[image]

This screenshot shows the print view for the report. What I would like to do is style the "Summary" row to a more noticeable color for the print view. I understand that I would probably have to modify the print customization function for databables, but based on some research, the classes are not exported the print view, so I cannot style a class or ID fo the row.

I can't seem to find any articles on this particular issue, so I am not entirely sure where to start, but here is the code that I currently have for generating my print view:

```
customize: function ( win ) {
            $(win.document.body)
                .css( 'font-size', '10pt' )
                .prepend(
                    `<style>@page{size: landscape;}</style>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div style="width:100%;">

                            </div>
                            <div style="float: right;">
                                <h2>Payment ID: ` + $('#ddl_payment_payment').val() + `</h2>
                                <h4>Payment Date: ` + paymentTable.cell(0,3).data() + `</h3>
                                <h4>Sub-contractor: ` + $('#ddl_payment_subContractor').val() + `</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
                )
                .append(
                    `<div class="container">
                        <div style="float:right;">
                            <h4>Total: ` + $('#span_paymenttotal').html() + `</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
                );
            $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                .addClass( 'compact' )
                .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
            $(win.document.body).find('summaryRow')
                    .css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to add custom formatting to the print-view of a DataTable.

First, here is the HTML datatable:

[image]

And here is what the print-view looks like:

[image]

The implementation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',

      buttons: [
        {
          extend: 'print',
          autoPrint: false,
          exportOptions: {
            format: {
              body: function ( inner, rowidx, colidx, node ) {
                if (node.classList.contains('summary')) {
                  return '<span class="summary" style="color:red; font-style:italic;">' + inner + '</span>';
                } else {
                  return inner;
                }
              }
            }
          },
          customize: function ( win, butt, tbl ) {
            $(win.document.body).find('span.summary').css('font-size', '20px');
            $(win.document.body).find('span.summary').parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');
          }
        } 
      ]

    });

  });
</script>
```

Explanatory notes:

In my data, I have inserted a `summary` class into those cells I want to manipulate - for example:

```
<tr>
    <td class="summary">Bradley Greer</td>
    <td class="summary">Software Engineer</td>
    <td class="summary">London</td>
    <td class="summary"></td>
    <td class="summary">2012/10/13</td>
    <td class="summary">$132,000</td>
 /tr>
```

There is no style associated with this class name.

For my demo, I just hard-coded these. But DataTables provides various ways to handle this dynamically, as part of the table initialization and data processing.

Then I use the `format.body` feature (described on [this page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData)). I use this to alter the data content (specifically, the font color) of all cells using the `summary` class.

The key here is to create a span which adds back the stripped-out class name. As you note, the print processor removes all such manually-added classes and styles from the print-view.

Now I can use the `customize` function (documented on [this page](https://datatables.net/reference/button/print)) to make use of my newly-added class name. For each relevant `span`, I find the parent `td` and adjust its style.

*Final note: to print out the bacground shading, I had to select a "print background" option from the print menu - that's probably just my printer, though.*

Hope that helps - or at least gives you some ideas for your specific needs.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I quickly read over this and it looks like it should help. I will take a look at it tonight and if dive a bit deeper into it. Thanks.

Comment: this worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!