# datatables print customize cell color

Tags: datatables

I'm tying to change the table cell color when printing a table.. The print cusomize fucntion is called and working correctly but the color doesn't change..

When I render the initial table I call rollCallback to set the cell color

```
rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
                    if(data.scores <= 1){
                        $(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'red');
                    }
                    if(data.scores > 1  && data.scores <=2 ){
                        $(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'yellow');
                    }
                    if(data.scores > 2){
                        $(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'green');
                    }
                   
                }
```

The in the print buttom. I use the same code to render the background color again

```
{
                    extend : 'print',
                    text : '<i class="fa fa-print fa-lg"></i>',
                    titleAttr : 'Print',
                    exportOptions : {
                        columns : [0,1,2,4]
                    },
                    customize: function(win,conf,table) {
                        

                        table.rows().every(function(index,element) {
                        
                            if(this.data().scores <= 1)
                            {
                                     $(this).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'red');
                            }
                             if(this.data().scores > 1  && this.data().scores <=2 )
                            {
                                     $(this).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'yellow');
                            }
                             if(this.data().scores > 2)
                            {
                                     $(this).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'green');
                            }
                
                    
                        });

    
                            
                            

                    }
                    
                }
```

The color does not change..
Im using
jquery-3.5.1
Datatables-1.10.21
buttons-1.6.3

Using @andrewjames answer I get a little better result.. The preview now has color.. but when ctrl-print is used from the browser I loose the style again.
[image]

Comment: The print pre-processor strips out all manually-added classes and styles from the print-view - as you are seeing. One workaround for this is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012722/conditionally-adding-styles-to-datatables-rows-in-print-view/62027183#62027183).

Comment: @andrewjames I included in my question the customize function that is mentioned in the link you provided. That is not working for me. All I'm trying to do is change the bg color of the cell. In the example you proveded he is doing a similar method call to change the font size

Comment: I added an example using the approach from that other answer - hope it helps to clarify. If I have misunderstood what you need to do, let me know, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach mentioned in my other answer, but adapted for your specific circumstances.

In my test data I only have 3 columns, so I made one small change from your code - I changed this `columns : [0,1,2,4]` to this `columns : [ 0, 1, 2 ]`.

Here is my starting table:

[image]

Here are some extra styles I added:

```
  <style>
    td.bg_red {
      background-color: red;
    }
    td.bg_yellow {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    td.bg_green {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
```

I used the following embedded test data (instead of an ajax data source):

```
var dataSet = [
    { "name" : "Tiger Nixon", 
      "office": "London",
      "scores" : 1 },
    { "name" : "Donna Snider", 
      "office": "New York",
      "scores" : 2 },
    { "name" : "Airi Satou", 
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "scores" : 3 }
];
```

Here is the DataTables definition:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var dataSet = [
    { "name" : "Tiger Nixon", 
      "office": "London",
      "scores" : 1 },
    { "name" : "Donna Snider", 
      "office": "New York",
      "scores" : 2 },
    { "name" : "Airi Satou", 
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "scores" : 3 }
];

  $(document).ready(function() {
  
    $('#example').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',

      data: dataSet,
      columns: [
          { title: "Name", data: "name" },
          { title: "Office", data: "office" },
          { title: "Score", data: "scores" }
      ],

      rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
        if(data.scores <= 1){
          $(row).find('td:eq(2)').addClass("bg_red");
        }
        if(data.scores > 1  && data.scores <=2 ){
          $(row).find('td:eq(2)').addClass("bg_yellow");
        }
        if(data.scores > 2){
          $(row).find('td:eq(2)').addClass("bg_green");
        }             
      },
      
      buttons: [
        {
          extend: 'print',
          //autoPrint: false, // useful for testing
          exportOptions: {
            //columns : [0,1,2,4],
            columns : [ 0, 1, 2 ],
            format: {
              body: function ( inner, rowidx, colidx, node ) {
                if (node.classList.contains('bg_red')) {
                  return '<span class="bg_red">' + inner + '</span>';
                } else if (node.classList.contains('bg_yellow')) {
                  return '<span class="bg_yellow">' + inner + '</span>';
                } else if (node.classList.contains('bg_green')) {
                  return '<span class="bg_green">' + inner + '</span>';
                } else {
                  return inner;
                }
              }
            }
          },
          customize: function ( win, butt, tbl ) {
            $(win.document.body).find('span.bg_red').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
            $(win.document.body).find('span.bg_yellow').parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');
            $(win.document.body).find('span.bg_green').parent().css('background-color', 'green');
          }
      } ]
      
    }); 

  });
</script>
```

And here is the print-preview:

[image]

This uses the same technique as described in the other answer I mentioned in my comments, but adapted for your specific scenario. The reason it works is the same as described in that answer.

**Update**

You may need to adjust printer settings to see the colors on an actual print-out. For example, using Google Chrome:

[image]

Comment: that worked for preview.. Now when printing(ctrl-p) it looses the style.. Happens with both chrome and safari

Comment: 2 points, in case they help: (1) You probably don't need `autoPrint: false`. It's useful for debugging more than anything else. (2) On my printer, I have the same problem because my printer is set, by default, to not show background graphics. I have a printer setting to control that - and then I get the colors when I print. Maybe you have something similar? I think it can vary from printer to printer (and printer drivers, too). Google Chrome's web printer also has a "background graphics" checkbox - does the same thing.

Comment: The image I added to my question show how the browsers treat the print control.. They call another browser preview(I assume) and the styles are lost.. Either that or I'm still doing something wrong.. I do have background graphics enabled on chrome.. but I still loose the styles

Comment: That's annoying. What if you use "Destination: Save as PDF"  in Google print? I am guessing you will have the same problem... Unfortunately I can't think of a way to recreate the problem on my side. (I am not using a Mac, by the way. I am using Windows 10.)

Comment: it is annoying.. but, thanks for spending some time with this..

Comment: so I messed with the code some more and found out that the problem is with bootstrap4 styling. If I use datatables with default or Jquery the background color works.. Once I use Bootstrap4 it stops working..

Comment: OK - that is good to know, thank you. I am not a Bootstrap user, myself. Maybe you can ask a new question, based on your research?